# autovaccum not started because of misconfiguration

Tags: postgresql

I am using postgresql9.0. I have setup Streaming replication. but when i started standby server using pg_ctl then I checked pg_log and found that it is writing following lines in log.

2011-12-08 09:37:19 ETC/GMT LOG:  could not bind IPv4 socket: Cannot assign requested address
autovaccum not statred because of misconfiguration
enable track counts option

track counts option will be on be default in postgresql9.0
So, please help me out to solve this problem...

Answer (score 1):

The error message is pretty clear. You must enable the config option `track_counts` for autovacuum to work. I [quote the manual for PostgreSQL 9.0](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/runtime-config-statistics.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-STATISTICS-COLLECTOR):

> track_counts (boolean)
>
> Enables collection of statistics on database activity. This parameter is on by default, because the autovacuum daemon needs the
>   collected information. Only superusers can change this setting.